# Как модифицировать список аргументов callback?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с такой вот задачей. Суть вкратце: необходимо передать свежесозданный аргумент в функцию, которая уже существует. Ниже код:

```
function baseFunc(age, name, callback)
{
    // Главная функция отработала, ajax вернул данные, теперь запускаем коллбэк на succsess
    // ...
    $.ajax(
    {
    // ...
    },
    sucsess: function()
    {
        // Ajax вернул номера телефонов
        var phones = [00000,11111]         

        if(callback)
        {
            // ГЛАВНЫЙ МОМЕНТ!!! Как мне добавить аргумент phones к исполнению в коллбэке?????
            callback();
        }
    });
}

// Коллбэк функция  
function callbackFunc(age, name, phones)
{

}

// В основной функции в какое то время должен отработать коллбэк. В нем помимо известных уже аргументов должен быть еще аргумент "phones", 
// который в настоящую секунду не существует, но появится позже   
baseFunc('20', 'Петя', function(){  callbackFunc('20', 'Петя', phones)  });
```

Comment: А что вам мешает взять его и добавить как любой другой параметр любой другой функции?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, может как дубликат по асинхронщие закрыть?

Comment: @Grundy а какая связь?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну так он хочет использовать значение phones, которое получает после запроса на сервер

Comment: @Grundy именно так

Comment: Как ты думаешь, в твоем вызове `baseFunc('20', 'Петя', function(){  callbackFunc('20', 'Петя', phones)  });` какая функция соответствует параметру `callback`?

Comment: @Grundy думаю function()

Comment: Что мешает добавить этой функции параметр для телефонов и при вызове передавать твою переменную?

Comment: `baseFunc('20', 'Петя', callbackFunc);`, а в success `callback(age, name, phones )`

Comment: @Grundy смысл в том, что неизвестно точное количество возвращенных параметров. Может быть только phones, а может быть phones, city, address и т.д.

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov такие вещи надо писать в вопросе, а не где-то там в комментариях

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov у Вас вариантов для манёвра куча. Самый простой вместо phones собирать и передавать объект `{phones : {}, address:{}, city:{}} `

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавить phones в определение колбека:

```
baseFunc('20', 'Петя', function(phones){  callbackFunc('20', 'Петя', phones)  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте указывать `arguments`, т.е. `arguments[0],arguments[1]` и `phones` в Вашем случае.

Т.е. `callback(arguments[0],arguments[1],phones);`

Должно работать если я правильно понял задачу :)

Comment: не должно, потому что вызов идет в коллбэке success, у нее свои аргументы, да и смысла нет, так как на данный момент, он передает функцию _без параметов_